# What did the prophet (PBUH) said to the bounty hunter who accepted Islam during Hijrah and what is his name?

Tags: history

During the hijrah of rasulullah (salallahu alayhi wa sallam), he was with Abu Bakr in the cave while the mushrikeen sought him out. Unable to find him, they placed a significant bounty on his head.

One particular bounty hunter managed to find rasulullah and Abu Bakr; but whenever he would approach them, his horse sank down into the sand and wouldn't move. [This website](http://wikiz.info/islam/lopm/chptr17.htm) states:

> After a few moments the search parry decided that no one could have
> entered the cave recently, or the spider's web would not have been
> complete and the dove would not have nested there, and so they left
> without searching inside. Three days later the Prophet (pbuh) and Abu
> Bakr thought it safe to leave the cave. Abu Bakr's son, 'Amir, had
> arranged for three camels and a guide to help them continue their
> journey to Yathrib. 'Amir would ride behind his father.
>
> The leaders of
> Quraysh, meanwhile, returned to Mecca and offered a reward of one
> hundred camels to whoever captured the Prophet (pbuh). Among those who
> went in search of him was a famous warrior. He was, in fact, the only
> one to catch up with him, but whenever he came close, his horse would
> suddenly sink up to its knees in the sand. When this had happened
> three times, he understood that the Prophet (pbuh) was protected by a
> power stronger than anything he had known, and so he went back to
> Mecca. On arriving there he warned everyone against continuing the
> search, relating what had happened to him.

I believe, although I cannot find any information about it currently, that this particular bounty hunter accepted Islam.

To avoid making this question too broad, I would like to know, particularly, **what rasulullah told him after he accepted Islam**, and **his name (fulan ibn fulan) and clan.**

Anything else is bonus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

His name was **Surakah bin Malek bin Jash'am** سراقة بن مالك بن جشعم, his is **clan Banu Mudlaj** (بني مدلج), part of [Banu Kinanah (بنو كنانة)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banu_Kinanah)

**He didn't actually accept Islam when he was following the prophet Muhammad (PBUH), i.e, during Hijrah.** What happened at this time is that he followed the prophet and Abu Bakr seeking the bounty Quraish offered for the one who finds the prophet. And, as the quotation in the question says: He was, in fact, the only one to catch up with him, but whenever he came close, his horse would suddenly sink up to its knees in the sand. When this had happened three times, he understood that the Prophet (pbuh) was protected and that he won't capture him. He asked the prophet to ask Allah let him go and, in return, he would tell Quraish that they won't be able to capture the prophet. The prophet asked Allah and Allah answered to him, Surakah asked the prophet to give him a paper that remains between both of them, the prophet asked Abu Bakr to write it and gave it ho him, among what the prophet said to Sarakah at that time (and probably was written in the paper):

> كيف بك إذ تسورت سواري كسرى
>
> What do you say about wearing the bracelets
> of Kisra (Chosroes كسرى)

At the day of Fath Mekkah (the conquer of Mekkah), Surakah went to the propeht (PBUH) to join Islam **(this is when Surakah joined Islam)**, and showed him the paper, the prophet said:

> يوم وفاء وبر، أدن ، ألا لا إيمان لمن لا أمانة له ، ولا دين لمن لا عهد
> له
>
> This is a day of fulfillment and devotion. Approach [O Surakah], indeed, who has no
> honesty has no faith, and who isn't faithful to his promises isn't
> faithful to his religion.

This was a "confirmation" from the prophet (PBUH) to the promise that Chosroes' bracelets are for Surakah.

At the Khilafah of Omar bin Al Khattab (Radya Allah 'anhu), Persia was conquered and the bracelets of Chosroes were among the spoils, Omar fulfilled the promise and prophecy of the prophet, he called Surakah (who was an old man) and made him wear them, in such a great event :)

Answer (score 4):

I'll answer from what I have read from Ar-Raheeq Al-Makhtum - The Sealed Nectar, by Saifur Rahman al-Mubarakpuri

The person is - **Suraqah ibn Malik ibn Ju'sham al-Mudlaji**

He is from **Bani Mudlij**.

I know that he accepted Islam but I couldn't find what the Prophet (salallahu alayhi wassalam) told him after he accepted Islam. However, there are many narrations reported from him. It is also known that he got the jewels of persia.

Insha Allah, if I find anything, I will update this answer.

Meanwhile, you might find [this](http://www.icfbayarea.org/www.icfbayarea.org/files/YCNotes/Lessons_From_The_Lives_Of_Those_Who_Went_Astray/Lesson_8_Abu_Jahl_Part5.pdf) useful.

**Source:** [Migration of the Prophet](http://abdurrahman.org/seerah/SN/sealednectar/20.html).